# No seleccionado, botón sin texto "android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout". ¿Cómo poner texto al ojo para que lo lea el talkback?

Tags: android

Estoy utilizando `android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout` para revelar la contraseña escrita a través del botón [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] .

Necesito asignar el texto "ver contaseña" para que lo lea el talkback o voice assistant, he intentado por varias opciones (`hint`, `contentDescription`, `tag`) y sigue locutando "botón sin texto". ¿Existe algún atributo que me permita poner el texto?.

Este es el código que estoy utilizando:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/login_password_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="57dp">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:id="@+id/editTextPas"
        android:contentDescription="@string/boton_verPass"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="false" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! Deberías mejorar la pregunta añadiendo el código que hayas probado para conseguir [un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: el `contentDescription` lo haces en el `xml`o en el codigo con: [`setContentDescription(CharSequence)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:contentDescription)?

Comment: Hola @MiquelColl. Lo hago en el xml.

Comment: @SBL, usa android:imeActionLabel

Answer (score 2):

Puedes realizarlo agregando las propiedades:

```
android:hint="@string/hint_password"
```

Y

```
android:imeActionLabel="@string/login_sign_in"
```

Este es un ejemplo:

```
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/my_password"
            style="@style/LoginEditText"
            android:hint="@string/hint_password"
            android:imeActionLabel="@string/login_sign_in"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: he agregado las dos líneas que mencionas y el talkback sigue locutando "no seleccionado, botón sin texto".

Comment: Ejecuto en un terminal con android 6.0.1 API level 23